# node js - Hashing a pwd in the mongoose pre('save'...) doesn't store to db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, hash

when I use the mongoose .pre('save'...) to hash my pwd, it works, but then the actual stored value to the db is the not-hashed value. Why does it reset? Thanks.

```
user.password = 'abcd';

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

    console.log('this.password: ' + this.password); // returns abcd

    bcrypt.hash(this.password, secret.pwdHashSecret, null, function(err, hash) {
        if(err)
            return next(err);

        this.password = hash;

        console.log('this.password: ' + this.password); // returns hashed pwd

        next();
    });
});

user.save(function(err) {

    console.log('user.password: ' + user.password); // returns abcd???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every function has it's own `this` value. You are adding a `password` property to the `this` value of the `bcrypt.hash` callback function. You should modify the `password` property of the outer function's `this` value. One option is storing the `this` value of the outer function and using it in the callback:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();
    var _this = this;
    console.log('this.password: ' + this.password); // returns abcd

    bcrypt.hash(this.password, secret.pwdHashSecret, null, function(err, hash) {
        if(err)
            return next(err);

        _this.password = hash;

        console.log('this.password: ' + _this.password); // returns hashed pwd

        next();
    });
});
```